# Responsive design and margins

Tags: css, css-position, responsive-design-view

With responsive designs, I heard we should use "%" instead of fixed measurements like "px" .
But it doesn't work how it should with margin?
I have a logo and links underneath it.
I added margin-bottom: 2% underneath it and it looks perfect from pc
But the links still overlap kinda in mobile.
What to do?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: #header {margin-bottom: 2%}

Comment: FYI, use percent to be responsive does not mean you can't use pixels.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the html/css or all we can do is guess.

Comment: I can share the url of the page.. http://opae.a-superlab.com/forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a negative margin on #page-header of -16px which is pulling the links back up...

Answer (score 0):

Float your logo to force margin-bottom to work or use padding-bottom instead.